# Can I use a wireless keyboard and mouse when first installing Ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, keyboard, mouse, bluetooth

I have Intel NUC Skull Canyon coming in a week and other stuff like a bluetooth keyboard and mouse.

How can I install the Ubuntu/ Xubuntu with a bluetooth keyboard and mouse?

This is the [bt keyboard](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01K1BWA7S).

I only have the experience in installing Ubuntu on my laptop but never did it on this kind of case before. Did anyone install Ubuntu/ Xubuntu with a bluetooth keyboard and mouse before? Please give some advice and and tips.

Or maybe better off using the wired keyboard and mouse??

Comment: You can if they work from LiveUSB. But this is not always the case.

Comment: @Pilot6 what is the LiveUSB?

Comment: It is the device you install Ubuntu from.

Comment: LiveUSB is the USB drive  with Ubuntu installer. I personally use wireless Logitech k400r keyboard when installing and it works, so yeah - that one is supported for sure

Comment: @Serg thanks . so not all bt keyboards work with Linux then?

Comment: @teelou  If drivers for keyboard come with the default system, they will work. If there's no drivers - they won't. Simple as that. Same as in Windows. You have drivers, windows will like it, if not - it won't.  Linux or not, idea is the same

Comment: @Serg what do u mean by 'drivers'? the software for the bt keyboard?

Comment: Keep in mind that if you want to get to the bios update with F2 or F7, before installing an OS even from a Linux LiveImage USB drive, you'll need a wired USB keyboard. My Logitech Wireless Keyboard Mouse does not work until the OS is up and drivers are running. On my Skull Canyon, Fedora 25 would not some up; Ubuntu, no issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the comments, if there are drivers for your wireless keyboard in default installation, it will work. Otherwise, no drivers - won't work.

According to one of the question on the Amazon page you linked, that keyboard doesn't work with Linux. Source:

https://www.amazon.com/ask/questions/Tx2ZBAUN8RZULG0/?source=allQuestionsPage

Although, according to the seller, it works in Android, so that answer isnt 100% reputable, I'd say.

Wired keyboards, particularly USB ones, are supported fully, so I would recommend you use that if you are unsure. Then after installation try testing your Bluetooth keyboard, maybe it'll work

Comment: Thanks for the answer but what do u mean by 'drivers'? the software for the bt keyboard?

Comment: Yes, the software.

Comment: I have never thought that a bt keyboard has a driver. But I know some bt keywords come with receivers. Are receivers = software?

Comment: No, receiver is typically a physical device. For example, the keyboard i mentioned, logitech k400r , has a tiny usb receiver which plugs into computer, and that's how keyboard and computer communicate - through that tiny device.

Comment: so if the bt keyboard has no usb receiver, like the one in my question, then it won't work?

Comment: @teelou see small update i made to the answer

Comment: Thanks for the update. `Although, according to the seller, it works in Android, so that answer isnt 100% reputable, I'd say.` - yes I doubt too.

Comment: @teelou yes, essentially, if there's no device that can receive bluetooth signal , it will not work. In my case, my laptop has WiFi card that has bluetooth receiver chip on it, built-in. My other laptop has no such thing, so I would probably need a Bluetooth receiver that plugs into USB port

Comment: I think I will use a wired keyboard as a backup. Thanks!

Comment: Always welcome ! Hope your installation goes smoothly. Have fun with Ubuntu !

Comment: Thanks. Will update my question if I have a good result :-)